# Accessing multidimensional stdClassObject - Array

Tags: c#, php, arrays, soap

I want to access the array properties I get as a SOAP-Resonse from a server. I use the php soapclient and and get the following output when using

```
$response = $client->$action($clientID);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), True);
```

Unfortunately I cannot get access to the properties such as 'tid', 'answer' etc. How can I do this (I can either use php or c# where I import the result)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tid] => 4103
                    [tdid] => 191
                    [qid] => 4103-1
                    [question] => Wie würden Sie Ihren Gesundheitszustand im Allgemeinen beschreiben ?
                    [answer] => Ausgezeichnet.
                    [score] => 100
                    [date] => 1558593404
                    [Fields] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tid] => 4103
                    [tdid] => 191
                    [qid] => 4103-2
                    [question] => Im Vergleich zum vergangenen Jahr, wie würden Sie Ihren derzeitigen Gesundheitszustand beschreiben ?
                    [answer] => Derzeit etwas besser als vor einem Jahr.
                    [score] => 75
                    [date] => 1558593404
                    [Fields] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )
```

Comment: how have you tried to access the objects?

Comment: `$array[1][0]->tid` what did you tried so far ?

Comment: when I try this I get:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpsy.php on line 20
Notice: Trying to get property 'tid' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpsy.php on line 20

Comment: that's probably because it doesn't exist in the first empty array

Comment: $tid = ($array[1][1]->tid); returns

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpsy.php on line 20

Comment: try `$tid = ($array[1][1])->tid` then

Comment: That returns: 
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpsy.php on line 19

Comment: Is it really the `var_dump($array);` that are you showing in your post ?

Comment: When I do a var_dump, I get

string(40000) "41031914103-1Wie würden Sie Ihren Gesundheitszustand im Allgemeinen beschreiben ?Ausgezeichnet.100.00000155859340441031914103-2Im Vergleich zum vergangenen Jahr, wie würden Sie Ihren derzeitigen Gesundheitszustand beschreiben ?Derzeit etwas besser als vor einem Jahr.75.00000155859340441031914103-3Im folgenden sind einige Tätigkeiten beschrieben, die Sie vielleicht an einem normalen Tag ausüben. Sind Sie durch I

etc...

Comment: I don't think you are var_dumping the right variable. What you've shown and the error you describe don't match, also what is $xml?  I think this needs editing

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the result, can you try this?

```
// assuming $array is the array that you described

$tid = ($array[0])->tid;
```

because $array is an array of Objects, so i assume to get the data is as simple as using the property accessor `->`. so $tid

you can learn more about php objects [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

hope it helps!

-- EDIT --

it should be `($array[1][0])->tid`. Because $array[0] is empty. you can use PHP's array_filter to remove all the empty arrays in $array.

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function($el){
  return count($el) > 0;
});
```

`$filtered_array` should only have non-empty arrays in it. but do take note that array_filter preserves array keys.

then, you can get all the objects with foreach loops.

```
// say you want to put all tids in an array

$array_of_tids = [];
foreach($filtered_array as $array_of_objects){
  foreach($array_of_objects as $response_objects){
    $array_of_tids[] = $response_objects->tid;
  }
}
```

the simpler but more unreliable (since i don't know the API response's consistency), would be to just use the index.

```
$tid_of_first_object = ($array[1][0])->tid
// $tid_of_first_object would be '4103'
```

let me know if it's still not working!

Comment: $tid = ($array[0])->tid   returns:
Notice: Trying to get property 'tid' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpsy.php on line 20

Same goes for $tid = ($array[0][1])->tid

Comment: hi @woofcheck can you try the edited answer? thanks! let me know if thing's are still not running.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays of objects, so to access them you need to use `$array[index/key][index/key]` until you reach the level the object's at, then use `[]->` to access it.

you are presumably going to loop through so inside your loop you would need to do some checks such as `is_array`,`isset`,`is_object`, or a `count` to see if there's anything to do, it would look something like this:

```
foreach($result as $arr) {
    if(count($arr) < 1) continue;//there are no entries in this array
    foreach($arr as $obj) {
      if(isset($obj->tid)) {
          //do your stuff
      }
    }
}
```

You could possibly simplify this by pulling all the data our using `array_column` if you just need the tid, it depends what your goal is - but this should set you in the right direction.  You might also look at `array_map`depending on what you need